# ListView not refreshed properly

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I am implementing a `Page` which has a `ListView` showing the items from an `ObservableArray<Expense>`. The handler for ListView's loadMoreItems appends 10 new items to the ObservableArray. The problem is that when I scroll down, the `amount` property of `Expense` on some rows is not shown.
The expense itself has the property set (as visible from the `onTap()`).

[image]

- [list-view-model.ts](https://gist.github.com/jorotenev/c1f53c7cbdf47802c1a6e7bf243fd43f#file-list-view-model-ts)
- [list.xml](https://gist.github.com/jorotenev/c1f53c7cbdf47802c1a6e7bf243fd43f#file-list-xml)
- [list.ts](https://gist.github.com/jorotenev/c1f53c7cbdf47802c1a6e7bf243fd43f#file-list-ts)

Sometimes the "amount" of two consecutive expenses is not shown, sometimes it's once every 10 expenses.  I deployed it on an actual phone too - same behaviour.
I [played with it](https://gist.github.com/jorotenev/af2314b97d2ed7ab84551a597c2e161b) and noticed that if I stick the Label that prints the `amount` into the innermost StackLayout (where the other two Labels are), it all works correctly. It messes up the layout though so it's not a viable solution.

Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4931) on GitHub. My issue was confirmed as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As @tsonevn suggested [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4931#issuecomment-336916562), in  `list.ts` change the `loadMoreItems()` to:

```
export function loadMoreItems(ev: EventData): void {
    // https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4931
    console.log("loadMoreItems");
    const fireEventAfter = 100; //ms
    setTimeout(() => {
        listModel.loadMoreItems(ev);
    }, fireEventAfter);
}
```

Additionally, delete `node_modules/, hooks/ & platforms/`.

Originally it was suggested to set the delay of `setTimeout` to 0ms (i.e. `const fireEventAfter = 0`), which did not make a difference in my case.